# CustomView UILabel Set Text Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom view - DetailSubView.h with labels

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *descHeaderLabel;
```

On custom UICollectionViewCell, i have

```
@property   (strong, nonatomic) DetailSubView          *detailView;
```

When I set text, i received unrecognized selector error.

```
[self.detailView.titleLabel setText:@"text"];
```

Comment: post stack trace and console log for better understanding of problem

Answer (score 0):

That's because your titleLabel is declared in DetailView but you're trying to access it from a class of type DetailSubView. It cannot access the getter method for your property on DetailSubView since you don't have it declared there.

Comment: OK. Typo. TitleLabel is in DetailSubView.h

Comment: Can you add the console message to your question? Also, post more code if you can....